# PyFPDF produces vertical text

Tags: python, fpdf, pyfpdf

Some time ago, I translated a PHP script to python, but I am getting a few problems more recently. (it's a script to generate voting ballots)

**The code:**

The full code is here: https://pastebin.com/ULAF1Nh5

The part that prints the voting options (the candidates' names and parties) is around line 403:

```
    #Now we have the text, we calculate how tall it is
    current_option_height = getOptionHeight(current_option_text,left_padding,right_padding)
    #Write the option out
    pdf.set_left_margin(left_margin+left_padding+(current_column*column_width)+oval_column_width)
    pdf.set_xy((left_margin+(current_column*column_width)+left_padding)+oval_column_width,current_column_y+OVAL_HEIGHT*2)
    WriteHTML(current_option_text)
    print(current_option_text)
```

The getOptionHeight function just returns the height of a given text.
The WriteHTML function just converts html text to python text and writes it on the pdf :

```
def WriteHTML(html):
    #HTML parser
    html = html.replace('\n',' ')
    a = html.replace('<BR>','\n')
    a = a.replace('</B>','<B>')
    a = a.split('<B>')
    for i in a:
        if a.index(i)%2 == 0:
            #Normal
            pdf.set_font('Helvetica','',11.5)
            pdf.write(OPTION_LINE_HEIGHT,i)
        else:
            #Bold
            pdf.set_font('Helvetica','B',11.5)
            pdf.write(OPTION_LINE_HEIGHT,i)
```

**The problem:**
At first, the script works. The first texts fed into it are:

```
President and Vice-President of the United States
Vote for 1 pair
<B>Joseph R. Biden<BR>and<BR>Kamala D. Harris</B><BR>Democratic
<B>Donald J. Trump<BR>and<BR>Michael R. Pence</B><BR>Republican
<B>Jo Jorgensen<BR>and<BR>Jeremy F. "Spike" Cohen</B><BR>Libertarian
```

(each option is written separately)

Which yields this (as expected):
[image: Perfectly-generated part of the ballot]

However, as soon as it draws another part of the ballot, it starts writing text vertically:
[image: Even the 2000 Palm Beach County ballots were better]

Why? And how can I fix it?